# PHP: Print one value from var_dump from API

Tags: php, json, soap, soap-client, var-dump

I am working on an `API` call using `PHP`. The `PHP` script uses `SOAP` and `JSON-RPC`.  It does work but I am having trouble getting only one value from the script to print instead of the entire data dump. From what I read, var_dump returns variable, type, value. I specifically only want to pull the value of one variable.

The end of my script is:

```
$jsonRpcRequest = array (
'method' => 'login',
'params' => array($merchantCode, $now, $hash),
'jsonrpc' => '2.0'
);
$ID = callRPC((Object)$jsonRpcRequest, $ApiUrl, true);
$productID = 4627344;
try {
$ProdID = $client->getProductById($ID, $productID);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
echo "Product ID: " . $e->getMessage();
}
var_dump ($ProdID) ;
```

The script works as I get all the product data for this product id. However, I only want to print the value of price, not the entire dump.

script results:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (24) {["ProductId"]=> int(4627344)["ProductEnabled"]=> bool(true) ["ProductType"]=> string(7) "REGULAR" ["ProductVersion"]=> string(0) "" ["Price"]=> float(1450) ["Currency"]=> string(3) "USD"
```

I have tried using various examples from online but I cannot seem to only call the price.

The desired result:
    1450

Comment: did you try `var_export()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat it like any normal object, use the `->` arrow notation for accessing properties:

```
$price = $ProdID->Price;
echo $price;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps a ton! (This is the first of many scripts for the API.)